# Oracle 10g database optimization

Tags: oracle, optimization

Sorry for my English.
I have so big DB on Oracle 10g. 
And I have queries, which executed so slow. For example, I have query :
115559 rows – 102 seconds

Execution plan:

```
Plan hash value: 3664903106

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name                | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                      |                     |      1 |  30503 |     50 |00:00:09.33 |    3989 |    33M|  2065K|   29M (0)|
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER             |                     |      1 |  30503 |    115K|00:00:05.71 |    3989 |   862K|   862K| 1186K (0)|
|   3 |    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN             | IX2_SLCND           |      1 |   1387 |   1387 |00:00:00.01 |      17 |       |       |          |
|*  4 |    HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER            |                     |      1 |  30503 |    115K|00:00:05.47 |    3972 |   785K|   785K| 1145K (0)|
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL               | DISC                |      1 |     90 |     90 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |       |       |          |
|*  6 |     HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER           |                     |      1 |  30503 |    115K|00:00:05.24 |    3965 |   776K|   776K|  403K (0)|
|   7 |      VIEW                           | index$_join$_030    |      1 |      2 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       6 |       |       |          |
|*  8 |       HASH JOIN                     |                     |      1 |        |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       6 |   760K|   760K|  464K (0)|
|   9 |        INDEX FAST FULL SCAN         | IX_CMP_NAME         |      1 |      2 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|  10 |        INDEX FAST FULL SCAN         | PK_CMP              |      1 |      2 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|* 11 |      HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER          |                     |      1 |  30503 |    115K|00:00:05.01 |    3959 |   756K|   756K| 1066K (0)|
|  12 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL             | TTYPE               |      1 |     26 |     27 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |       |       |          |
|* 13 |       HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER         |                     |      1 |  30503 |    115K|00:00:04.78 |    3952 |   767K|   767K|  416K (0)|
|  14 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL            | COMMTCOMP           |      1 |      2 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |       |       |          |
|* 15 |        HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER        |                     |      1 |  30503 |    115K|00:00:04.54 |    3945 |   760K|   760K| 1037K (0)|
|  16 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL           | TTYPE               |      1 |     26 |     27 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |       |       |          |
|* 17 |         HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER       |                     |      1 |  30503 |    115K|00:00:04.31 |    3938 |   842K|   842K| 1267K (0)|
|  18 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL          | SLRSSEASONTC        |      1 |   2885 |   2974 |00:00:00.01 |      53 |       |       |          |
|* 19 |          HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER      |                     |      1 |  30503 |    115K|00:00:04.07 |    3885 |   909K|   909K| 1178K (0)|
|  20 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL         | CAR                 |      1 |    976 |    976 |00:00:00.01 |      16 |       |       |          |
|* 21 |           HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER     |                     |      1 |  30503 |    115K|00:00:03.84 |    3869 |  1036K|  1036K| 1169K (0)|
|  22 |            INDEX FULL SCAN          | PK_STP              |      1 |    258 |    258 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |       |       |          |
|* 23 |            HASH JOIN                |                     |      1 |  30503 |    115K|00:00:03.60 |    3868 |   778K|   778K| 1165K (0)|
|  24 |             TABLE ACCESS FULL       | WKST                |      1 |     83 |     83 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |       |       |          |
|* 25 |             HASH JOIN               |                     |      1 |  61027 |    115K|00:00:03.37 |    3861 |   804K|   804K|  924K (0)|
|  26 |              VIEW                   | index$_join$_014    |      1 |     12 |     12 |00:00:00.01 |       6 |       |       |          |
|* 27 |               HASH JOIN             |                     |      1 |        |     12 |00:00:00.01 |       6 |   783K|   783K|  919K (0)|
|  28 |                INDEX FAST FULL SCAN | IX_BRANCH_NAME      |      1 |     12 |     12 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|  29 |                INDEX FAST FULL SCAN | PK_BRANCH           |      1 |     12 |     12 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|* 30 |              HASH JOIN              |                     |      1 |  61027 |    115K|00:00:03.13 |    3855 |   808K|   808K| 1166K (0)|
|  31 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL     | USERS               |      1 |     96 |     96 |00:00:00.01 |      16 |       |       |          |
|  32 |               MERGE JOIN            |                     |      1 |    115K|    115K|00:00:02.90 |    3839 |       |       |          |
|* 33 |                HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER|                     |      1 |    115K|    115K|00:00:02.32 |    3838 |   848K|   848K| 1169K (0)|
|  34 |                 TABLE ACCESS FULL   | STP                 |      1 |    258 |    258 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |       |       |          |
|* 35 |                 HASH JOIN           |                     |      1 |    115K|    115K|00:00:01.95 |    3831 |   848K|   848K| 1169K (0)|
|  36 |                  TABLE ACCESS FULL  | STP                 |      1 |    258 |    258 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |       |       |          |
|* 37 |                  HASH JOIN          |                     |      1 |    115K|    115K|00:00:01.52 |    3824 |   848K|   848K| 1169K (0)|
|  38 |                   TABLE ACCESS FULL | STP                 |      1 |    258 |    258 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |       |       |          |
|* 39 |                   HASH JOIN         |                     |      1 |    115K|    115K|00:00:01.09 |    3817 |    10M|  1956K|   12M (0)|
|* 40 |                    TABLE ACCESS FULL| SL                  |      1 |    116K|    120K|00:00:00.01 |    2115 |       |       |          |
|* 41 |                    TABLE ACCESS FULL| SLTC                |      1 |    114K|    115K|00:00:00.19 |    1702 |       |       |          |
|* 42 |                SORT JOIN            |                     |    115K|      1 |    115K|00:00:00.27 |       1 | 73728 | 73728 |          |
|* 43 |                 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN   | PK_CMP              |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |       |       |          |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("SLCND"."ID"="SL"."ID")
   4 - access("SL"."DISC_ID"="DISC"."ID")
   6 - access("CARI"."ID"="SLTC"."CARI_ID")
   8 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
  11 - access("TTYPE"."ID"="SLTC"."TTYPE_ID")
  13 - access("CTC"."ID"="SLRSSEASONTC "."ID_COMMTCOMP")
  15 - access("RS"."ID"="SLRSSEASONTC "."COMMTTYPE_ID")
  17 - access("SLRSSEASONTC "."ID"="SLTC"."ID")
  19 - access("CAR"."ID"="SLTC"."CAR_ID")
  21 - access("STP"."ID"="WKST"."DEF_STP_ID")
  23 - access("SL"."POS_WKST_ID"="WKST"."ID")
  25 - access("USERS"."BRANCH_ID"="BRANCH"."ID")
  27 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
  30 - access("SL"."USR_CAS_ID"="USERS"."ID")
  33 - access("SLTC"."THSTP_ID"="THSTP"."ID")
  35 - access("SLTC"."TSTP_ID"="TSTP"."ID")
  37 - access("SLTC"."FSTP_ID"="FSTP"."ID")
  39 - access("SLTC"."ID"="SL"."ID")
  40 - filter(("SL"."WHEN_DATE">=TO_DATE('2001-10-29 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND "SL"."SCOMP_ID"=1 AND 
              "SL"."WHEN_DATE"<=TO_DATE('2013-10-29 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')))
  41 - filter("SLTC"."MANUAL"='N')
  42 - access("SL"."SCOMP_ID"="CMP"."ID")
       filter("SL"."SCOMP_ID"="CMP"."ID")
  43 - access("CMP"."ID"=1)
```

I need ideas to make db faster.
Thanks You!

p.s.
I’m new in databases

Comment: somehow your joins to STP are not optimal - need to see the SQL

Answer (score 0):

So yeah, a you have a pretty horrible execution plan there.

To optimise the query, **we would need the query as well**, but I'll try to give you a few hints using just your exection plan output.

See all the `TABLE ACCESS FULL`? This is what usually takes time! Try using indexes on your tables, it seems that there are too few indexes used here (probably because no other indexes exist). Based on the execution plan, here are some simple indexes that might work, you may try them out:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_sltc_id ON sltc(ID);
CREATE INDEX ix_sl_id ON sl(ID);
CREATE INDEX ix_sltc_manual ON sltc(manual);
CREATE INDEX ix_sl_scomp_id ON sl(SCOMP_ID);
CREATE INDEX ix_sl_pos_wkst_id ON sl(POS_WKST_ID);
CREATE INDEX ix_sltc_thstp_id ON sltc(THSTP_ID)
CREATE INDEX ix_sltc_thstp_id ON sltc(THSTP_ID);
CREATE INDEX ix_sltc_tstp_id ON sltc(TSTP_ID);
CREATE INDEX ix_sltc_fstp_id ON sltc(FSTP_ID);
```

Without the query itself, we are quite limited here and probably missing most of the picture. Using the query, we could then try to create composite indexes, that are much more efficient.

More importantly, it seems that you do not use PRIMARY KEYs on your tables, because there are a lot of TABLE ACCESS FULL operations on tables with the predicate "ID". Make sure all your "ID" columns are indexed as well (or defined as PRIMARY KEY if that is indeed the primary key).

Also, we see that the optimizer does not have correct statistics, try to manually refresh the statistics for your schema:

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.delete_schema_stats('SCOTT');
```

And as a sidenote: Whoever designed this schema, educate this person on database design!

Another sidenote for the more advanced readers: While `TABLE ACCESS FULL` is not always bad (there are quite a few cases where a full table scan is faster than access via indexes), it often indicates missing indexes. So setting the indexes and refreshing the statistics should provide a performance gain here.

Comment: Thanks You!
May be You can help with this question:
Why if in my query I request data for week in this month I get result 10x faster then, if I request data for week, for example, in April?
Thanks You!